# Open web page with POST data without using webview

Tags: android, post, browser, http-post

I want open one web page from my app.

I have this code:

```
String url = "http://www.example.com";
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

But http://www.example.com needs one POST variable.

How can I pass one POST parameter without using the webview?

Comment: A Web browser will use `GET`, not `POST`, for your URL. You can change your server to support `GET`, then use standard `?name=value` query parameter syntax on `url`. Otherwise, neither the `POST` nor the query parameter are going to work via `ACTION_VIEW`.

Comment: You should use a library to perform HTTP POST request like Retrofit : https://square.github.io/retrofit/, in the documentation it's written how call REST url's passing POST parameters

Comment: I need POST not GET , i have already use Retrofit library , But i need open the browser either and i have passed the data via POST method;

Comment: Hi @SalimLachdhaf,

Did you solve this issue? If you did, kindly share.